# AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: Missing access token for source AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, sits

I use sits in R on Windows 10 in order to receive satellite images from Amazon Web Services. It worked out already, but now I get this error message:

```
bfmn <- sits_cube(
  source="AWS",
  collection="SENTINEL-S2-L2A",
  dir="C:/temp/final2",
  bands = c("B02","B03","B04","B05","B08","B11","B12","SCL"),
  start_date = "2019-03-01",
  end_date = "2019-06-04",
  roi=AOI,
  delim = "_",
  multicores = 2,
  progress = TRUE)
```

```
Error: sits_cube: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID:  Missing access token for source AWS (nzchar(Sys.getenv(x)) is not TRUE)
```

What do I set as  AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID? Does this I mean I have to log in in order to able to use the service?
Thanks

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19045)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.utf8  LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.utf8    LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.utf8 LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=German_Germany.utf8    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] RPostgres_1.4.4

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.9      lattice_0.20-45 here_1.0.1      png_0.1-8       withr_2.5.0     rprojroot_2.0.3 rappdirs_0.3.3  grid_4.2.2      lifecycle_1.0.3
[10] jsonlite_1.8.4  DBI_1.1.3       rlang_1.0.6     cli_3.4.1       rstudioapi_0.14 blob_1.2.3      Matrix_1.5-1    ellipsis_0.3.2  vctrs_0.5.1    
[19] reticulate_1.27 tools_4.2.2     bit64_4.0.5     bit_4.0.5       hms_1.1.2       compiler_4.2.2  pkgconfig_2.0.3
```

Answer (score 1):

it seems to me that your function is trying to access the environment variable `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`.

double check that you have that value set using `echo $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` for Linux/mac

Comment: I am using windows, sry for not mentioning

Comment: for windows please refer to this https://geekflare.com/system-environment-variables-in-windows/

Comment: But can I use the package without signing in Amazon? The function already worked for me using AMS.

Comment: there seems to be nothing wrong with the code, you just need to set up those environment variables on your machine and it should work again

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/de_de/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html#envvars-set I followed these steps, but it's still not working.

Comment: Found the error! In the collection argument we need to add "-COGS" to "SENTINEL-S2-L2A", in order to acess the open data collection. Thanks anyway for the help!